# All product flavors are concatenating to one build variant

Tags: android, build

In my project, I have created product flavors:  `blue`, `green`, `red`. But when I look into build variant it shows me `blueRedGreenDebug`, `blueRedGreenRelease`. As you can see in below images.

Product Flavor
[image]

Build Variant
[image]

Comment: Please show me the entire `build.gradle`  file, So I'll give you a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this it will definitely help you.**

```
flavorDimensions "paid", "free", "other"

productFlavors {

            blue {
                targetSdkVersion 27
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                versionNameSuffix 'blue'
                dimension "paid"
                applicationId "com.itroom.productFlavors.blue"
            }
            green {
                minSdkVersion 15
                targetSdkVersion 26
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                dimension "other"
                applicationId "com.itroom.productFlavors.green"
            }
            red {
                targetSdkVersion 27
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                versionNameSuffix 'red'
                dimension "free"
                applicationId "com.itroom.productFlavors.red"
            }

        }
```

**Replace with**

```
flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {

        blue {
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            versionNameSuffix 'blue'
            applicationId "com.itroom.productFlavors.blue"
        }
        green {
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            applicationId "com.itroom.productFlavors.green"
        }
        red {
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            versionNameSuffix 'red'
            applicationId "com.itroom.productFlavors.red"
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors) you must define flavorDimensions.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {
        debug{...}
        release{...}
    }
    // Specifies one flavor dimension.
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            // Assigns this product flavor to the "version" flavor dimension.
            // This property is optional if you are using only one dimension.
            dimension "version"
        }
        full {
            dimension "version"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            flavorDimensions "default"

                productFlavors {

                    APP1{
                        applicationId "com.project.androidone"
                        versionCode 1
                        versionName "1.0"
                        flavorDimensions "other"
                        signingConfig signingConfigs.businessConfig

    setProperty("archivesBaseName","PROJECT_V1_$versionName.$versionCode")
                        }


                   APP2{
                        applicationId "com.project.androidtwo"
                        versionCode 1
                        versionName "1.0"
                        flavorDimensions "paid"
                        signingConfig signingConfigs.businessConfig

    setProperty("archivesBaseName","PROJECT_V1_$versionName.$versionCode")
                          }

                   APP3{
                        applicationId "com.project.androidthree"
                        versionCode 1
                        versionName "1.0"
                        flavorDimensions "free"
                        signingConfig signingConfigs.businessConfig

    setProperty("archivesBaseName","PROJECT_V1_$versionName.$versionCode")
                        }
                }
```